# Postgres ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING query

Tags: python, postgresql

Hi I am trying to run statement below but it doesn't work:

```
cursor.execute("""insert into  sentiment_history values ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s' ON CONFLICT (UNIQUE_SENTIMENT) DO NOTHING)""" % (dt, longs_sentiment, shorts_sentiment, sentiment_inline, significant_sentiment_change, market_id))
```

UNIQUE_SENTIMENT - is a constraint that I created

This is the error I see:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 1: ...40.035000','65.0','35.0','FALSE','FALSE','2YRTND' ON CONFLIC...
```

Fixed

Query should be in this format:

cursor.execute("""insert into  sentiment_history values ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s') ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_SENTIMENT DO NOTHING""" % (dt, longs_sentiment, shorts_sentiment, sentiment_inline, significant_sentiment_change, market_id))

Comment: Close the parentheses after your values, before the `ON CONFLICT` statement. Then remove the close parenthesis after `DO NOTHING`.

Comment: Just tried that this is the error I now get: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "unique_sentiment" does not exist
LINE 1: ...5.0','35.0','FALSE','FALSE','2YRTND') ON CONFLICT (UNIQUE_SE...

Comment: Never use python string substitution to create a SQL statement.  Please read the psycopg2 docs.  It will save you from a world of pain dealing with quotes and special characters and may save you from SQL injection.